# How to emit in the close method of Reducer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

The `close` method inherited from `MapReduceBase` has no argument:

```
public void close()
```

So I don't have `OutputCollector` as `reduce` method does:

```
void reduce(K2 key, Iterator<V2> values, OutputCollector<K3, V3> output, Reporter reporter)
```

In the new hadoop API, I find the Reducer class has a `setup` method:

```
void setup(Context context)
```

I think the context argument can emit key and value.
The problem is I have to use the old API and I don't know how to emit in the close method.
What I want is to run some code when the last time reduce method is called and emit data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unfortunate you are using the old API. The new API has a [`cleanup`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.html#cleanup%28org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context%29) method (complements `setup`).

I wonder if Hadoop will let you cheat and store the `OutputCollector` in a private data member in your Reducer class, then refer to that in the close method. I'm guessing you can't, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: Your suggestion of storing the OutputCollector in an instance variable is a good one - I believe you actually can do this, although I'm not positive.

Comment: You can do this, you'll need to add some logic to your reduce method to cache the reference to the OutputCollector if the reference is null

Comment: I stored the `OutputCollector` and successfully emit data in `close` method. Thank you.

Comment: To huozinbird: could explain how you did that? Was it by just storing the outputcollector in another variable and then use that variable in the close() method to output?