# How to emit in close() method in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to emit in the close method of Reducer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557007/how-to-emit-in-the-close-method-of-reducer)

How is it possible to emit the final result of mapper in the *close* method of the *mapper* class? Where should the result be stored? Can someone explain it by writing some code for me? Thanks.

Comment: OK... so it's not exact duplicate...

Answer (score 1):

This is some sample Mapper code based on a similar answer for this same function in a Reducer.

```
public class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    private OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> collector = null;

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

        // Mapper logic goes here

        collector = output;

    }

    public void close() {

        // Write to private variable collector here...

    }
}
```

Comment: can someone point me to the similar questions where I can find the answer?

Comment: @Hessam Look at the top of this question at the link in the box... Right under "Possible Duplicate".  I've modified that other answer for mappers in my answer here (the other one was for reducers).